# decode byte array implicit string on xelement

Tags: vb.net

I am having a problem "decoding" information of a XElement that has a value of byte() on it's information.
Let's consider the following codeline:

```
Dim c = <test><value><%= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is a test") %></value></test>
```

When I call `c.ToString`, the call returns me the following data:

```
<test>
  <value>11610410511532105115329732116101115116</value>
</test>
```

Now, how can i "decode" the value element sample to be "this is a test" again?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your encoding is impossible to decode; you can't tell how to break up the decimal digits into bytes.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: You would be better off using base-64 encoding on the string of bytes - unless this is a third-party interface that you don't have any control over.

Comment: To be clear, I have created an ORM that saves automatically class information to database; on this situation, "value" is a property of byte array, and with reflection I read the properties information to save it on a LOG in XElement format. Because it is done with reflection, I didn't specified the type of the conversion, so the sample is like the information i get for now. I guessed it could be "decoded"

Comment: Generally byte arrays in XML are encoded as base64. I don't have time to show a full answer on this topic right now, but you might want to search on base64 xml byte array for your answer.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Thank you for your help, I know how to decode-encode on base64, but in this situation, as SLaks said, there aren't separators to know how to "decode" it.Thanks anyway.

Comment: @FernandoAndrsSepulvedaSilva My point is that with base64 you don't need to worry about separators, so you should be encoding with base64 instead of whatever this is.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Understood, thank you again!